# Moving Libs from Root to /libs

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

righ now i'm using Flex 4.1 libs, when compiling Flex puts all used libs into the root of the application, however - i don't want them there, i want them to be inside Flex_root/libs.

Anyone a clue where i can change the lib location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the framework files (swz) you can't change their location without also changing location of your application.

If you want to compile all this into a single file, you can turn off RSLs, then you'll only get one result file, not a bunch of different files.

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about the swz's. I want to keep it RSL but i don't want such an unorganized mess flying around in my public folder - thats what lib folders are for. So, really no chance changing the location of them to a more re-useable location?

Comment: The libs folder is for your own libraries / SWC files.  It's a Flash Builder invention strictly for the purpose of automatically adding items to the class path.  It has nothing to do w/ release builds.